# Parse JSON as key value in Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How to parse `JSON` data in `apache beam` and store in `bigquery` table ? 
For example: JSON data

```
[{ "name":"stack"},{"id":"100"}].
```

How to parse JSON data and convert to `PCollection` K,V that will store in BQ table?
Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would use a built in JSON parser in the programming language (Are you using beam or python). Then create a TableRow object and use that for the PCollection which you are passing to the BQ table.

Note: Some JSON parsers disallow JSON which starts with a root list, as you have shown in your example. They tend to prefer something like this, with a root map. I believe this is the case in python's json library.

> {"name":"stack", "id":"100"}

Please see this [example pipeline](https://github.com/bomboradata/pubsub-to-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bombora/pubsub/to/bq/PubSubToBQPipeline.java#L100), for an example on how to create the PCollection and use BigqueryIO.

You may also want to consider using one of the X to [BigQuery template pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates).